# Why my second foreach dont output anything?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I don't know why second `foreach` in Main doesn't work like intended. I wanted to serialize a list then convert it to Array, sort it, convert to list again and then serialize it, but my deserialization kinda doesn't work and I don't know why.

My class library:

```
[Serializable]
public class Kolekcja<T> : ISerializable, IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private List<T> lista = new List<T>();
    [NonSerialized]
    private int liczba1, liczba2;
    [NonSerialized]
    private int suma, roznica, iloczyn;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lista.Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        lista.Remove(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int item)
    {
        lista.RemoveAt(item);
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return lista.GetEnumerator();

    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return lista.GetEnumerator();
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        List<T> lista2;
        T[] tablica;
        //wariant1
        tablica = lista.ToArray();
        Array.Sort<T>(tablica);
        info.AddValue("tablica", tablica, typeof(T[]));
    }

    public Kolekcja(SerializationInfo sinfo, StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        T[] tablica = (T[])sinfo.GetValue("tablica", typeof(T[]));
        lista = new List<T>(lista);
    }

    public Kolekcja()
    {

    }

    public Kolekcja(List<T> lista)
    {

    }

    public int Count => lista.Count;
    //public int Count { get {return lista.Count;}}
    public T Max => lista.Max();
    public T Min => lista.Min();

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return lista[i]; }
        set { lista[i] = value; }
    }

    public static bool operator <(Kolekcja<T> a, Kolekcja<T> b)
    {
        return a.Max.CompareTo(b.Min) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Kolekcja<T> a, Kolekcja<T> b)
    {
        return a.Min.CompareTo(b.Max) > 0;
    }
}
```

My Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Kolekcja <int> numbers = new Kolekcja<int>();
        numbers.Add(1);
        numbers.Add(3);
        numbers.Add(2);
        
        foreach(var el in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el);
        }
        Stream fs = new FileStream("data.dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        bf.Serialize(fs, numbers);

        fs.Close();

        fs = new FileStream("data.dat", FileMode.Open);
        bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        numbers = (Kolekcja<int>) bf.Deserialize(fs);

        foreach (var el in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el);
        }

        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

I don't really know if I miss something or I did my deserialization wrong, I tried google it but nothing really help and it seems like I don't understand serialization yet.

Comment: Side note: while entertaining make sure to keep your usage of BinaryFormatter to just educational purposes - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this: *my deserialization kinda doesnt work*?  Does it return null? Does it throw exception? Other?

Comment: @PeterCsala it doesnt show anything actually :D

Comment: @Mezus Please check my post. I've found your bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following bug:

```
public Kolekcja(SerializationInfo sinfo, StreamingContext ctx)
{
    T[] tablica = (T[])sinfo.GetValue("tablica", typeof(T[]));
    lista = new List<T>(lista); //bug
}
```

Here is the fix:

```
public Kolekcja(SerializationInfo sinfo, StreamingContext ctx)
{
    T[] tablica = (T[])sinfo.GetValue("tablica", typeof(T[]));
    lista = new List<T>(tablica);
}
```

Comment: I thank you so much!! And im happy that it was small mistake (also sorry for Polish words, it had to be confusing)